# With Twitter oAuth authorization, how do you specify what twitter username?

Tags: oauth, twitter

Developing a web application that I've registered with Twitter.  In this app, I might have 10 different Twitter Identities that I want to either Allow or Deny access for the application to.

For example:

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_callback=http:://localhost:24649/TwitterIdentity/GetTwitterAuthorizationCallback/

It always just defaults to whatever my twitter account is logged in as and I have to specify Logout, then sign-in with new account.  Its almost like I need an extra querystring parameter such as

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_callback=http:://localhost:24649/TwitterIdentity/GetTwitterAuthorizationCallback/**&ForUsername=billgates**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the general scope of authorization, the authorized agent does not necessarily know the identity of the user on whose behalf it acts. In other words, there could be an implementation where your app can be authorized to read the Twitter stream of updates, while still not knowing which identity that stream belongs to. Adding the parameter you ask for would be information disclosure in this case, as your app will need a piece of information that the system is designed not to provide.

Or to put it in a real life example - imagine a valet parking, where instead of giving you a parking ticket and taking the keys to the car, the valet would ask you for your SSN just to park the car, just because the valet parks cars for other people too.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to get the login out of the session when hitting the authorize page.  It seems like it's not technically possible.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Once your app is authorized, you most probably can get the identity from Twitter API. So, you could keep assoiciation of authorization tokens and identities. You just can't request authorization for specific identity.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  I have a table that i store the request token in during authorization, then upon callback, I match it up via that request token.  So I will know the user.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can pass in an extra parameter with the callback url, like so:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_callback=http:://localhost:24649/TwitterIdentity/GetTwitterAuthorizationCallback?ForUsername=billgates
```

and the parameter will be sent back to you when Twitter calls the return url, like this:

```
http:://localhost:24649/TwitterIdentity/GetTwitterAuthorizationCallback?ForUsername=billgates&oauth_token=XXX&access_token=YYY
```

You can read more about this in the documentation - http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth:

> **Always use an explicit oauth_callback**
>   - It is recommended that you specify a default OAuth callback in your client
>   record, but explicitly declare your
>   oauth_callback on each request token
>   fetch request your application makes.
>   **By dynamically setting your
>   oauth_callback, you can pass
>   additional state information back to
>   your application** and control the
>   experience best.